# Avoid Multiple submission on button works on desktop version but not on mobile version like iPhone

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Avoid Multiple Submission in asp.net webform works on desktop version but not on mobile version of safari or chrome on iphone.

Below script stops users from multiple submission of same form by changing the text of submit button to "wait..." after form is submitted & validated properly

This script works fine on desktop version but doesn't change text of button to "wait.." on iPhone default browser or chrome browser. Not sure what could be wrong as i am not able to troubleshoot it

BUTTON
`<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Submit" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ValidationGroup="vgForm" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="ClientSideClick(this)" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />`

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Submit" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ValidationGroup="vgForm" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="ClientSideClick(this)" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />


  //Avoid Multiple Submission
        function ClientSideClick(myButton) {
            // Client side validation
            if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
                if (Page_ClientValidate("vgForm") == false) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            //make sure the button is not of type "submit" but "button"
            if (myButton.getAttribute('type') == 'button') {
                // diable the button
                myButton.disabled = true;
                myButton.className = "btn-inactive";
                myButton.value = "Wait...";
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: are you not using post-redirect-get pattern? https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-post-redirect-get-pattern/

Comment: @Hooman, I am using asp.net webform 4.5 not MVC

Comment: Post-redirect-get is a pattern, you can use it with webforms too, if you wanted too ;-) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3x8t37x.aspx. The idea is to redirect successful Posts to a get method, to avoid multiple submission.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button once it is clicked.

```
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" onclick="this.disabled = true; this.value= 'wait...'" value="Submit">
```

And if you have any success call back, then you can enable it again.

Comment: I dont want to disable button only but also to show  text on button to "wait.." after form is validated properly

Comment: @Learning Updated the answer. You can wrap that onclick event in javascript function.

Comment: I need to call function to validate `ClientSideClick(this)`, validation part works but only text is not changes in mobile version. on desktop i have no issues.

Comment: @Learning It is weird. I am wondering, rather than passing it as "this", can you try getting the button as document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').value = 'Wait...'